# can't able to access ms-acess database 2010

Tags: java, database, ms-access-2010

Can anyone help me , why i cant be able to access ms-access database.
pls find fault in my code.

```
protected String processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        int e_no=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("enrollment_no"));
        String branch=request.getParameter("branch");
        String sem=request.getParameter("semester");
        String f_name=request.getParameter("first_name");
        String l_name=request.getParameter("last_name");
        String email=request.getParameter("email");
        String pass=request.getParameter("password");

        Connection con;
        Statement stm;

        try {                
                String driver="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
                Class.forName(driver);
                String db="jdbc:odbc:practicedb";
                con=DriverManager.getConnection(db);
                stm=con.createStatement();
                String query="insert into studenttbl values='"+e_no+"','"+branch+"','"+sem+"','"+f_name+"','"+l_name+"','"+email+"''"+pass+"'";

                stm.executeUpdate(query);
                out.println("Database Successfuly added");

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {                
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: post the error that you're getting

Comment: It run successfully without any error but i not able insert the data in database.

Comment: For one thing, your insert statement is missing parenthesis. It should be on the form `insert into studenttbl values (...)`. If you suspect an error you might want to print out the exception generated (if any).

Comment: @AbielPaltao, i m new to this,
So can u tell me for which generated exception i print out??

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

```
String database = "FILE PATH ON YOUR LAPTOP";
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + database + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true";
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
    java.sql.Statement stm = con.createStatement();
```

Also, add a `catch statement` just before the return null.

---

As pointed by @jpw, you might want to double check your insert query. It should be something like this:

```
String query="insert into studenttbl values('"+e_no+"','"+branch+"','"+sem+"','"+f_name+"','"+l_name+"','"+email+"''"+pass+"')";
```

Comment: i have try this also but can't able to insert value

Comment: can you `System.out.println(e.toString());` to your catch statement and post the error.

Comment: also, does your msaccess file is hosted on your pc or over cloud?

Comment: Edited my answer. I assumed that you're using a mdb (msaccess) file.